# Quartz cronSchedule para rodar com intervalo maior que uma hora

Tags: java, job, quartz-scheduler

Estou querendo fazer um cronSchedule do quartz assim

```
cronSchedule("0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *")
```

porém ele fica rondando de 5 em 5 minuto exemplo

> 7:05, 7:10, 7:15, ... e assim por diante

O que estou precisando é assim

> 7:05, 8:10, 9:15, ... e assim por diante

**(intervalo de uma hora e cinco minutos)**

- Tem como fazer isso usando o **cronSchedule**?

Comment: Precisa ser com cronSchedule? Eu usaria `simpleSchedule().withIntervalInMinutes(65).repeatForever()`

Comment: Atualmente faço na forma que sugeriu, queria fazer da outra forma para padronizar em somente um recurso (uma forma de parametrizar todos os jobs)

Comment: Sinceramente, acho que a padronização nesse caso não vai valer a pena. Expressões *cron* usam intervalos fixos por unidade, até onde vai meu conhecimento você vai precisar escrever várias expressões para chegar ao mesmo resultado do *simples trigger* acima.